# HTTP : What is the difference between SC_NOT_FOUND and NOT_FOUND

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I am using spring for my project and a question arises in my mind that what is the basic difference between these two  `HttpStatus`

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND).body("Email address not found");

return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Token Expired");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is from the apache servlet API for status codes from Interface HttpServletResponse found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)

> SC_NOT_FOUND   - Status code (404) indicating that the requested
>   resource is not available.

The second one is from spring framework http status codes constants from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html)

> NOT_FOUND 404 Not Found.

For spring Framework (& spring boot) the second one is used widely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, it is same status code for HTTP from different libraries.